# GLOBAL vs global keyword

Tags: matlab, global

I'm studying a MATLAB code in which I found this:

```
GLOBAL = eye(4,4);
```

what is `GLOBAL`? Is it a global variable? Documentation says that global variables are declared in this way:

```
global x1 = 4;
```

What are the differences between `GLOBAL` and `global`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Somebody must have used it as a variable name which could work but at least should be considered very bad practise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a little script which highlights the difference:

```
clear all;
global x1;
x1 = 4;
GLOBAL = eye(4,4);
whos
```

As you can see in the workspace `x1` is a global variable, whereas `GLOBAL` is not:

```
 Name        Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  GLOBAL      4x4               128  double              
  x1          1x1                 8  double    global
```

Edit: you could even declare `GLOBAL` globally: `global GLOBAL` which then leads to:

```
  Name        Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  GLOBAL      4x4               128  double    global    
  x1          1x1                 8  double    global
```

Comment: Nice table showing the differences. Would saying that `global global` is valid syntax be very obfuscating?

Answer (score 3):

`GLOBAL = eye(4,4);` indeed makes `GLOBAL` a variable. This is not too bad, as MATLAB is case sensitive, though not very clear of course. The documented version you found is [`global`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html) in lower case. I'd suggest not naming variables the same as built-in functions, e.g. if you calculate a sum don't call it [`sum`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html) but `Summed` or something; don't call an average [`mean`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html), but `Avg` etc.

Comment: You beat me by 10 seconds! I just want to point out that it is possible to check whether a string is a reserved word by using the iskeyword function, see http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/iskeyword.html

Comment: @A.Darwin or by simply typing `which global` which will tell you it's a built-in as well.

Comment: Good answer on case sensitivity and also helpful additional comments! :)